# When to use HttpServletRequest class in a Spring Mvc Controller

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc

I am reading a book about spring and in the chapter about spring mvc the author list the following controller code that is responsible for form submission.
My question (since the author is not referring to it is why and where we should use HttpServletRequest)
Here is the method :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", params = "form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String update(@Valid Contact contact, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Locale locale)
    {
        logger.info("Updating contact");

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
        {
            uiModel.addAttribute("message", new Message("error", messageSource.getMessage("contact_save_fail", new Object[]{}, locale)));
            uiModel.addAttribute("contact", contact);
            return "contacts/update";
        }

        uiModel.asMap().clear();
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", new Message("success", messageSource.getMessage("contact_save_success", new Object[]{}, locale)));
        contactService.save(contact);
        return "redirect:/contacts/" + UrlUtil.encodeUrlPathSegment(contact.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it whenever you need to use it...

In this example, the author is using it get the character encoding :

```
return "redirect:/contacts/" + UrlUtil.encodeUrlPathSegment(contact.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest);
```

Here is the code from the [UrlUtil class](https://code.google.com/p/springblog-by-hand/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/prospring3/web/util/UrlUtil.java?r=5) :

```
public class UrlUtil {
    public static String encodeUrlPathSegment(String pathSegment, HttpServletRequest
            httpServletRequest) {
        String enc = httpServletRequest.getCharacterEncoding();
        if (enc == null) {
            enc = WebUtils.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_ENCODING;
        }
        try {
            pathSegment = UriUtils.encodePathSegment(pathSegment, enc);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        }
        return pathSegment;
    }
}
```

More information about the `HttpServletRequest` class :

It extends the `ServletRequest` interface to provide request information for `HTTP` servlets. You might consider reading the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) if you want to learn more about the methods of the class.